# Replacing value in a column that contains specific label and to replace them

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace

i have a pandas dataframe with a column named period with 3 different labelling value which means winter 2019, winter 2020 and winter 2021 as shown below

my question is how do i replace this format with the end result being winter 2019, winter 2020 and winter 2021?

```
Period:
Q4 '19+Q1 '20 
Q4 '20+Q1 '21
Q4 '21+Q1 '22
```

Q means quarter in a year

So my approach is:
1) first is the regex method to make a new year column. I extract the '19, '20, '21 year number after the first Q4

```
gas['year'] = gas['Period'].str.extract("([']\d\d)", expand=True)
```

Then i plan to  replace value containing Q4 and Q1 with winter by

```
gas['Period'].str.contains('Q4')) & (gas['Period'].str.contains('Q1')) = 'winter Gregorian'
```

but it replaced the whole row containing Q4 and Q1

also tried

```
gas[gas['Period'].str.replace("[Q][4]..\d\d[+][Q][1]", 'winter Gregorian'), regex =False]
```

and end result i would like something as:

```
Period
winter Gregorian 2019
winter Gregorian 2020
winter Gregorian 2021
```

but didnt work, i welcome any advice and suggestions
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make use of [regex capture groups](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/regex.html#grouping) here. Take a look at this regular expression:

```
(Q[0-9]) '([0-9]{2})\+(Q[0-9]) '([0-9]{2})
```

Each item enclosed in parentheses is a group that you can access after matching. For example, in `Q4 '19+Q1 '20`, the first group in the match is `Q4`, the second group is `19`, the third group is `Q1`, and the fourth group is `20`.

After matching your Period strings against this regex, you can pull out the group matches to construct your desired output format. This code gives you a complete example of how to do this.

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Period": [
        "Q4 '19+Q1 '20 ",
        "Q1 '20+Q2 '20",
        "Q4 '20+Q1 '21",
        "Q4 '21+Q1 '22"
    ]
})

pattern = "(Q[0-9]) '([0-9]{2})\+(Q[0-9]) '([0-9]{2})"
season_map = {
    ('Q4', 'Q1'): 'Winter',
    ('Q1', 'Q2'): 'Spring',
    ('Q2', 'Q3'): 'Summer',
    ('Q3', 'Q4'): 'Fall'
}

def convert_time_format(x):
    match = re.match(pattern, x)
    if match is not None:
        season = season_map.get((match.group(1), match.group(3)))
        year = match.group(2)
        return season + ' ' + year
    else:
        return 'Failed to parse'

df.Period.map(convert_time_format)
```

That gives:

```
0    Winter 19
1    Spring 20
2    Winter 20
3    Winter 21
```

Comment: hi mate thank you for your reply! just tried the code and got this error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: I'm guessing you ran it against your `df` and not the one in the example above? That error means that the regex didn't fully match one of the Period values. I just edited my answer to add better error handling- i.e. return the string 'Failed to parse' instead of erroring out.

Comment: hey i tried this with my original dataframe and it returned Failed to parse because i have something other than the 4 season. (but works fine with my 4 seasons) any way i could retain those other values? THANK YOU!

Comment: Yeah, you can change `return 'Failed to parse'` to `return x`, and that will retain the original value of the field. Glad I could help!

Comment: MATE THANK YOU! PROBLEM SOLVED, been trying to solve this for the whole day

Comment: Hi luke, i made my own version: pattern = "(\w+) '([0-9]{2})"
month_map = {
    ('January'): 'Jan',
    ('February'): 'Feb',
    ('March'): 'Mar',
    ('April'): 'Apr',
    ('June'): 'Jun',
    ('July'): 'Jul',
  
}

def convert_month(x):
    match = re.match(pattern3, x)
    if match is not None:
        month = month_map.get((match.group(1)))
        year = '20'+match.group(2)
        return month + '_' + year
    else:
        return x

gas['Period'] = gas.Period.map(convert_month)          TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: im not sure how to overcome this, i reckon it is the (\w+) but couldnt figure out where i have gone wrong

Comment: That error is happening because `month_map.get((match.group(1)))` is returning None, which means that `month` is None, which means that `month + '_' + year` is failing. Your `\w+` is matching something other than the name of a month, so `match.group(1)` is not found as a key in `month_map`.

Comment: For a quick fix, try replacing `if match is not None:` with `if match is not None and match.group(1) in month_map:`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can modify your regex to look for the month names explicity, i.e. `(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) '([0-9]{2})`

Comment: Also, heads up your `month_map` is missing May. Just adding that might even solve your problem too.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, mate you deserve a medal!

Answer (score 0):

so i produce my own version for to look for all month and format them and got this: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

```
pattern3 = "(\w+) '([0-9]{2})"
month_map = {
    ('January'): 'Jan',
    ('February'): 'Feb',
    ('March'): 'Mar',
    ('April'): 'Apr',
    ('June'): 'Jun',
    ('July'): 'Jul',
    ('August'): 'Aug', 
    ('September'): 'Sep',
    ('October'): 'Oct',
    ('November'): 'Nov',
    ('December'): 'Dec',
}

def convert_month(x):
    match = re.match(pattern3, x)
    if match is not None:
        month = month_map.get((match.group(1)))
        year = '20'+match.group(2)
        return month + '_' + year
    else:
        return x

gas['Period'] = gas.Period.map(convert_month)
```

sorry luke may have to bother you again